# instance variable being directly accessed

Tags: objective-c, clang

I downloaded XCDFormInputAccessoryView from github https://github.com/0xced/XCDFormInputAccessoryView. I tried to run it in xcode and receive numerous warnings of

instance variable "---" is being directly accessed. Any help??

```
- (void) setTextInputs:(NSArray *)textInputs
{
    // Some day, IBOutletCollection will be properly sorted, in the meantime, sort it!
    _textInputs = [textInputs sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UIView *view1, UIView *view2) {
        return [@(view1.tag) compare:@(view2.tag)];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the result of Cedric turning on the `-Weverything` flag, which makes LLVM generate pedantic warnings.  Remove the flag under your build settings:

[image: No more -Weverything]

Then recompile, and the errors should go away.

Answer (score 4):

Add `-Wno-direct-ivar-access` to the Warning Flags under Build Settings.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to retain as many warnings as practical, this is a strategy you could use in your base .xcconfig file:

```
TWX_BASE_WARNING_EXCLUSIONS = -Wno-bad-function-cast -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wno-objc-missing-property-synthesis -Wno-pedantic -Wno-unused-macros -Wno-used-but-marked-unused -Wno-selector -Wno-direct-ivar-access

WARNING_CFLAGS = -Weverything $(TWX_BASE_WARNING_EXCLUSIONS)
```

Personally, I have stacked .xcconfig files so the "base" there is as opposed to other files in the stack,

```
WARNING_CFLAGS = -Weverything $(TWX_BASE_WARNING_EXCLUSIONS) $(TWX_CONFIGURATION_WARNING_EXCLUSIONS)
```

and the same strategy is used for managing search paths, preprocessor definitions, etc.